# Azure Function App - Microsoft Graph modules could not be loaded

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have an Azure Function App running powershell script. I use Connect-MgGraph cmdlet to connect to Microsoft graph API but its failing with error as -

```cs
"**ERROR: The 'Connect-MgGraph' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication', but the module could not be loaded**. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Authentication'"
```

Can someone help resolve the error please ?

I have all the Graph modules available in Managed-dependency folder for this app. Also, I have also already added below required Modules as dependency management in Requirements.psd1.

```cs
'Microsoft.Graph' = '2.1.0'
'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication' = '2.1.0'
```

Also, tried to run Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Authentication explicitly in run.ps1 and through profile.ps1 but its not executed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands in run.ps1 to connect to Microsoft graph:

```
Import-Module  -Name Microsoft.Graph

Connect-MgGraph
```

**requirements.ps1:**

```
@{

'Microsoft.Graph'  =  '2.2.0'

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]